# Mathematica, leftover zeros

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm struggling how to get rid of expressions that are trivially zero in Mathematica from the output. 
Example:

```
    pVec = Table[{i, Exp[-i*0.03]}, {i, 0, 2.5, 1/2}]; 

    pVec[[2, 2]] = p1; 
    pVec[[3, 2]] = p2; 
    pVec[[4, 2]] = p3; 
    pVec[[5, 2]] = p4; 
    pVec[[6, 2]] = p5; 

    qq = Interpolation[pVec, InterpolationOrder -> 1]; 

>> qq[0.5] 
>> 0. (1 - p1) + p1
```

the `0*(1-p1)` is obviously zero, but I couldnt find a way to get rid of it ? (I'm relatively new to Mathematica...) Simplify didnt work, `N[ ]` didnt work `FullSimplyfy[ ]` as well.

Any advice ? Because in a big expression using this interpolation, these zero-expressions accumulate... and i have 10 line answer instead of a constant.

Comment: @Vyautas I see you have a good response already. I'll mention that as an alternative you might try collecting those zeros and sending them to some country that has a shortage of them. Costs next to nothing to send--zeros are quite light (some say they are massless, but I'm not convinced).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the function you require is `Chop`.

From the Help: "`Chop[expr]` replaces approximate real numbers in expr that are close to zero by the exact integer 0"

For example:

```
Chop@qq[0.5]
Chop[0.` (1 - p1) + p1]
```

both give as output:

p1